# Horizontal line in a Jumbotron

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I don't feel well. All of a sudden, an unwanted white horizontal line has appeared in the bottom of my jumbotron. It's happened after...

1. Inserting a navbar form
2. Adding a form at the bottom of the body
3. Inserting a  object then
4. inserting a button in the jumbotron

I've commented out all changes I've made, but to no avail.

```
<header class="jumbotron">
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <br><br><br><br><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='#reservation'">Reserve table</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0px">
<!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
            <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
            <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <br><br><br><br><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='#reservation'">Reserve table</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! You can relax everyone...

```
<div class="row row-content">
```

should have been

```
<div class="row row-header">
```